# How do I programmatically get the field type of a specific field?

Tags: entities, 8

I'm able to get a list of the field types with the following code.

```
$defs = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.field.field_type')->getDefinitions();
```

I want to get the field type of a specific field. How do I get it?

For example, I'd like to check if the field type of field_image is _image. Is there code similar to the following one?

```
$fieldType = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.field.field_type')->getDefinition('field_image');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With "get the field type of a specific field" you probably mean a specific field of an entity. There can be fields with the same name that have different types in different entities.

For example the field type of a field in a node:

```
$field_type = $node->get($field_name)->getFieldDefinition()->getType();
```

can be different than that of the same field in a comment:

```
$field_type = $comment->get($field_name)->getFieldDefinition()->getType();
```

Comment: When I used that it gave me the label I gave the field like 'Header Image', not the actual type of field it is. Like 'image', 'plain text' or 'list'

Comment: That's right, it is `getType()`.

Comment: Or a bit shorter, from the entity: $node->getFieldDefinition($field_name). Or if you don't have an entity, then you getn also get the storage definition directly with $entity_field_manager->getFeidlStorageDefinition('node', 'field_image')